# fb-hydra: How to make inner configurations inherit outer configuration fields PARTLY?

Tags: python, deep-learning, config, fb-hydra

I have 2 configs like, and I want to make inner config PARTLY inherit outer config. Thank you for your help!

this is the outer config:

```yaml
# config.yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - model: pct

lr: 1e-3 
num_epoch: 200
weight_decay: 5e-4
scheduler_stepsize: 50
batch_size: 16
```

this is the inner config:

```yaml
# model/pct.yaml
file_name: pct
lr: 1e-4
```

And I want to override the outer config PARTLY, such as inherit 'lr':

```yaml
# my expect output config
lr: 1e-4
model:
  file_name: pct
...
```

I know there is '@*here*' keyword to make inner config be global, but I do not know how to make inner config PARTLY be global.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I'd recommend that you use OmegaConf's [variable interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#variable-interpolation) capability.

```yaml
# config.yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - model: pct

lr: ${model.lr}
num_epoch: 200
```

```yaml
# model/pct.yaml
file_name: pct
lr: 1e-4
```

```py
# my_app.py
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
import hydra

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    OmegaConf.resolve(cfg)
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

Running the app:

```
$ python my_app.py
lr: 0.0001
num_epoch: 200
model:
  file_name: pct
  lr: 0.0001
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think this solution is just like delete ``lr`` in config.yaml, and directly use model/pct.yaml. However, I want to keep the default ``lr`` in config.yaml. So , when there is no ``lr`` in model/pct.yaml , I can use the default value in config.yaml.

Comment: Or may be what I need is ``if condition`` , but I do not find it in hydra by searching "if"